# Gcc not including Object.h

Tags: objective-c, gcc

I am just starting on doing objective-c with gcc (so far I only used XCode).

```
#include <objc/Object.h>  
@interface Integer : Object  
{  
int integer;  
}  
- (int) integer;  
-(id) integer: (int) _integer;  
@end
```

```
#import "Integer.h"  
@implementation Integer  
- (int) integer  
{  
    return integer;  
}  
- (id) integer: (int) _integer  
{  
    integer = _integer;  
}  
@end
```

And once I try to compile the stuff I get this:

```
main.m: In function ‘main’:  
main.m:8: warning: ‘Integer’ may not respond to ‘+new’  
main.m:8: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature  
main.m:8: warning: will be assumed to return ‘id’ and accept  
main.m:8: warning: ‘...’ as arguments.)  
main.m:8: warning: ‘Integer’ may not respond to ‘+new’
```

Seems to me that the inclusion of `Object.h` did not quite work. 
I searched thee includes for Object.h and got this:

```
find /usr/include/ -name Object.h   
/usr/include//objc/Object.h
```

Also the GCC output hints that the compiler *is* actually searching in that path.

```
 #include "..." search starts here:  
 #include <...> search starts here:  
 /usr/local/include  
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include  
 /usr/include  
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)  
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)  
End of search list.  
GNU Objective-C version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664) (i686-apple-darwin10)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664).  
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=150 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072  
Compiler executable checksum: 84137cc00ce86c64ee80a91a006f61ae  
main.m: In function ‘main’:  
main.m:8: warning: ‘Integer’ may not respond to ‘+new’  
main.m:8: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature  
main.m:8: warning: will be assumed to return ‘id’ and accept  
main.m:8: warning: ‘...’ as arguments.)  
main.m:8: warning: ‘Integer’ may not respond to ‘+new’`\
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Object has been deprecated since... 1995?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If gcc couldn't find Object.h, it would give an error indicating that. The problem is that Apple removed most of the methods from `Object` (or at least the interface for it) in Objective-C 2.0. Instead, you should subclass NSObject and include the Foundation framework.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the first line to

```
&#35;include &lt;objc/Object>
```

Comment: I was just told that Object.h is quite broken in OS X.